# Выдвигающееся меню (CSS+JS)

Tags: javascript, css3, css-animation

Есть код `https://jsfiddle.net/1gu1v13h/` 
HTML

```
<div id="wrapper"><!-- 
        <h3>CSS3 Animated Menu Toggle Icon</h3> -->
        <a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
</div>
```

по нажатию на значек меню сам значек немного меняется и хочу сделать, чтобы справа-налево выезжало меню (горозонтальное). Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант на css

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body { background-color: black;  
}

#nav-toggle{
  display: none;
}
#nav-toggle + label{
  position: relative; top: 15px; left: 15px;
  display: inline-block; 
  width:35px; 
  height:25px;   
}
#nav-toggle + label span { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 10px; }
#nav-toggle + label span, 
#nav-toggle + label span:before,
#nav-toggle + label span:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle + label span:before {top: -10px;}
#nav-toggle + label span:after {bottom: -10px;}

#nav-toggle + label ~ .b-menu{  
  position: absolute; top: 15px; right: 0;
  width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;  
  background: #ccc;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;  
}
#nav-toggle:checked + label ~ .b-menu{ 
  width: 200px; 
  /*padding: 15px;*/
}
#nav-toggle:checked + label span {background-color: transparent;}
#nav-toggle:checked + label span:before {transform: rotate(45deg);}
#nav-toggle:checked + label span:after {transform: rotate(-45deg);}
#nav-toggle:checked + label span:before,
#nav-toggle:checked + label span:after {top: 0;}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">          
      <input type="checkbox" id="nav-toggle" />
      <label for="nav-toggle"><span></span></label>
      
      <ul class="b-menu">
      <li><a href='#'>menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>menu 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Это лишь пример, поэтому можно сделать красивше.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#menu-right').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

#nav-toggle {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 25px;
}

#nav-toggle span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}


/* Добавим анимацию всех свойств для блоков нашей иконки */

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}


/* Центральный блок делаем прозрачным */

#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}


/* Смещаем псевдо-элементы в центр иконки (на место основного блока) */

#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}


/* Наклоняем псевдо-элементы под углом 45 градусов, но в разные стороны */

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu-right {
  background: #47a3da;
  position: fixed;
  right: -250px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.menu-right.open {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
  <nav id='menu-right' class='menu-right'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Hello</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>World</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```